# Init from nib, but alloc only [UIViewController]

Tags: objective-c

So I'm doing this in my code now:

```
UIViewController* ctrl =
     [[UIViewController alloc] // i'm alloc'ing a UIViewController...

       initWithNibName:@"TheNibName" // But this NIB has, within
       // interface builder, a link to "UIViewControllerDERIVATIVE".  So really,
       // `ctrl` is a UIViewControllerDERIVATIVE instance, not just
       // a UIViewController instance.

       bundle:nil] ;
```

The reason I'm doing this is it makes a massive convenience in writing some code that pushes modal dialogs on.. since Objective-C doesn't support <template>.

My question is, **is this ok??**  Can I `[alloc]` a `UIViewController` only, while really what comes out of a NIB is an instance of `UIViewControllerDERIVATIVE`?  Or will it bite me in the ass later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot allocate an `UIViewController` and initialize it as a `UIViewControllerDERIVATIVE`, because there will be a mismatch between the how the two classes see their instances.

Once an instance has been allocated by a class, it is the responsibility of the class to initialize it. This is because the class of the instance is set when the instance is allocated. See [NSObject reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-alloc) more details.

Comment: Yes, I discovered this actually, because the members that are in `UIViewControllerDERIVATIVE` don't actually get alloc'd.